# CSS Image Hover Weird Effect in Chrome Browser Only

Tags: css, hover

On this website, if you hover over the three horizontal image boxes underneath the homepage slider whilst using Chrome, on hover, the other two boxes are jumping down the page.

This problem doesn't happen in Firefox.

I've been playing around with the display:block property but haven't managed to get it sorted, if anyone could kindly advise what I'm doing wrong, it would be really appreciated - thanks.

Site: http://www.benchmemorials.co.uk/

Comment: I'm not seeing the issues in Chrome 18.

Comment: Thanks for checking beanland. Hmm, I'm using Chrome v17.0.963.83, maybe updating browser will make the problem go away. So none of the images / divs jump about when you hover over any one of the three images on homepage? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? I just viewed it with 18.0.1025.152 m and everything seemed to work properly. On hover, the "more info" links appeared and nothing jumped down the page. *Edit* never mind - I was too slow LOL

Comment: No issues. Chrome 20 (Canary).

Comment: I've just updated Chrome and yes, it's not happening anymore. Thanks for clarifying all :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have problem neither, but this kind of problem often come from margin and padding set by default in different browser. Check [normalize css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), it's will set for you some basic style on your elements.